# Why socklent_t * is used in accept() in socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

In C socket programming the `accept()` declaration looks like:

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

I can understand the uses of `sockfd`, `struct sockaddr *addr`.

But why we have to pass the address of the length of the socket, it could have been `socklen_t`. Because if the `accept()` function needs the length then it can get it by `socklen_t`. Why the protype of the function is declared in such that way?

So what is the reason behind using `socklen_t *` type?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9824719/694576

Comment: `socketlen_t` is a *type* that is used to declare a *variable* that can hold the length of a socket address, which itself is variable depending on the address family. It isn't that length itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code that's agnostic to the address/protocol family of the socket it's accepting from, it may be using a generic `sockaddr_storage` structure to hold the result. The initial value of the pointed-to `socklen_t` is the size of this storage; the value after `accept` returns is the actual size of the resulting peer address. Also, some address/protocol families like `AF_UNIX` have variable length addresses, so even if you know the type you may not know the size.

Comment: So is this for length as they can not get the size as they know the type?

Answer (score 4):

1. why addrlen is needed

   accept designed to deal with lots of protocal family, their addr struct  maybe different length.

> The argument addr is a pointer to a sockaddr structure.  This structure is filled in with
>       the  address  of the peer socket, as known to the communications layer.  The exact format
>       of the address returned addr is determined by the socket's address family (see  socket(2)
>       and the respective protocol man pages).  When addr is NULL, nothing is filled in; in this
>       case, addrlen is not used, and should also be NULL.

2. why pointer

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain
>       the  size  (in  bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the
>       actual size of the peer address.

3. why socklen_t

> The socklen_t type
>       The  third  argument  of  accept() was originally declared as an int * (and is that under
>       libc4 and libc5 and on many other systems like 4.x BSD, SunOS 4, SGI); a  POSIX.1g  draft
>       standard  wanted to change it into a size_t *, and that is what it is for SunOS 5.  Later
>       POSIX drafts have socklen_t *, and so do the Single UNIX Specification and glibc2.  Quot‐
>       ing Linus Torvalds:
>
> "*Any*  sane  library  *must*  have  "socklen_t"  be the same size as int.  Anything else
>       breaks any BSD socket layer stuff.  POSIX initially did make it  a  size_t,  and  I  (and
>       hopefully  others,  but  obviously  not  too many) complained to them very loudly indeed.
>       Making it a size_t is completely broken, exactly because size_t very seldom is  the  same
>       size  as  "int"  on 64-bit architectures, for example.  And it has to be the same size as
>       "int" because that's what the BSD socket interface is.  Anyway, the POSIX people  eventu‐
>       ally  got  a  clue, and created "socklen_t".  They shouldn't have touched it in the first
>       place, but once they did they felt it had to have a named type for some unfathomable rea‐
>       son  (probably  somebody  didn't  like  losing  face over having done the original stupid
>       thing, so they silently just renamed their blunder)."

ref: man accept, man socket