# What's the pad to sockaddr_in for?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm new to C and socket programming, still struggling in `sockaddr_in` structure:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   /* Protocol family (always AF_INET) */
    unsigned short   sin_port;     /* Port number in network byte order */
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     /* IP address in network byte order */
    unsigned char    sin_zero[8];  /* Pad to sizeof(struct sockaddr) */
};
```

and

```
struct in_addr {
   uint32_t s_addr; /* Address in network byte order (big-endian) */
};
```

I'm not sure about the need of `sin_zero` other than alignment requirement, below is my assumption, please correct me if I was wrong:

Assumption 1-since `sin_addr` is 32 bit for ipv4 address, if we need a ipv6 address, the the first 4 bytes of `sin_zero` will be assigned and combined with `sin_addr` to form a 64 bit ipv6 address.

Assumption 2-If my assumption is correct, then is the reason why we need to specific the length of a socket address such as:

```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

is because the possibility of ipv6 addresses? so if ipv4 is used, then `addrlen` should be 8, and if ipv6 is used, then `addrlen` should be 12?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609397/whats-the-difference-between-sockaddr-sockaddr-in-and-sockaddr-in6 `sizeof(sockaddr_in6) > sizeof(sockaddr) == sizeof(sockaddr_in)`  The reason sockaddr_in needs to be at least as large as sockaddr is  so that you can aallocate a sockaddr_in and then cast it to a sockaddr when passing it to a library function - it's a bit like inheritance for C.   sockaddr_in6 is already larger than sockaddr so it doesn't need any padding.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099041/why-do-we-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-when-calling-bind/21099196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple protocol families. Each family has its own address structure.

Example: `AF_INET` uses `sockaddr_in`, `AF_INET6` uses `sockaddr_in6`, `AF_UNIX` uses `sockaddr_un`, etc.  But `sockaddr` is the base structure. All these structures must be type-cast to `sockaddr` while binding/connecting a socket.

`int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);`

`int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);`

Let's look at the structures of  `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr`:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   /* Protocol family (always AF_INET) */
    unsigned short   sin_port;     /* Port number in network byte order */
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     /* IP address in network byte order */
    unsigned char    sin_zero[8];  /* Pad to sizeof(struct sockaddr) */
};


struct in_addr {
   uint32_t s_addr; /* Address in network byte order (big-endian) */
};
```

The structure of `sockaddr` is:

```
struct sockaddr 
{
    sa_family_t sa_family;
    char        sa_data[14];
}
```

Look at the sizes of the elements in the two structures `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr`.

The first element in both structures is the same and occupies the same memory.

`sin_port` --> 2 bytes
`sin_addr` --> 4 bytes
`sin_zero[8]` --> 8 bytes
Total = 14 bytes (equal to size of `sa_data[14]`)

We add padding bytes to make their structure sizes equal.

reference:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why we need to specify the length `addrlen` to `bind` functio, if both `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr` have the same size?

Comment: @amjad  See this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251960/why-socklent-t-is-used-in-accept-in-socket-programming

Comment: @amjad Other types of address structures DO NOT have the same size as `sockaddr`, for instance `sockaddr_in6` and `sockaddr_un` are much larger.